# Using LIKE with multiple criteria and columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, multiple-columns, hql-like

I'm trying to use HQL using `LIKE`, but I want to use multiple columns

Like this one but not only name field, lets take for example name and address `dateOfInscription`

```
String query = "from user u where u.name like :name"
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, "name", '%' + str + '%');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that this way:

```
        String query = ""
                + "from User where "
                + "u.firstName like '%" + firstName+ "%' ";
        if (!"".equals(lastName)) {
            query += "and u.lastName like '%" + lastName + "%' ";
        }
        if (!"".equals(bDate)) {
            query += "and u.bDate like '%" + bDate + "%'";
        }
        List<User> resultList = null;
        resultList = hibernateTemplate.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are doing a "search" functionality and want to search multiple columns based on user input. The following should work.

```
String query = "from user u where u.name like :name OR u.address like :address OR u.dateOfInscription like :dateOfInscription"
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, "name", '%' + str + '%', "address", '%' + str + '%', "dateOfInscription", '%' + str + '%');
```

Comment: sorry but you are comparing the address to name?? I want each one to have its LIKE, u.address like address , u.name like name

Comment: findByNamedParam gets (query, paramName, paramValue)